# Plone custom edit/add form using Dexterity/Grok

Tags: plone, dexterity, grok

I am trying to create a custom edit/add form for my form package that I built using Dexterity types. I am following the Schema-driven types tutorial on the Plone Developer Documentation in the [Dexterity Developer Manual](https://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/schema-driven-types.html#) section. So far I have successfully created a Dexterity package with two content types: FAQ and Question. My FAQ Dexterity content type is a container, and my Question Dexterity content type can only be added within my FAQ container.

**FAQ Content Type** - *FAQ.py*

```
from product.faq import MessageFactory as _
from five import grok
from plone.dexterity.content import Container
from plone.directives import dexterity, form
from zope import schema
from zope import interface

from Acquisition import aq_inner
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
from product.faq.question import IQuestion

class IFAQ(form.Schema):
    """ Project FAQ Container """

class FAQ(Container):
    grok.implements(IFAQ)

class View(grok.View):
    """ FAQ View Class """
    grok.context(IFAQ)
    grok.require('zope2.View')

    def questions(self):
        """ Return a catalog search result of questions to show """        
        context = aq_inner(self.context)
        catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')

        return catalog(object_provides=IQuestion.__identifier__,
                       path='/'.join(context.getPhysicalPath()),
                       sort_on='sortable_title')
```

**Question Type** - *Question.py*

```
from product.faq import MessageFactory as _
from five import grok
from plone.dexterity.content import Container
from plone.directives import dexterity, form
from zope import schema
from zope import interface

class IQuestion(form.Schema):
    """ Project FAQ Question Type """

    title = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Question"),
    )

    answer = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Answer"),
    )

    # Used to group questions into sections
    section = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Section"),
    )

class Question(Container):
    grok.implements(IQuestion)

class Edit(grok.Form):
    """ FAQ Question Edit Class """
    grok.context(IQuestion)
    grok.require('zope2.View')
```

I need to be able to customize the form markup for both the add and edit views. So far I have been able to create an Edit view with no functionally. How do I add the functionally back to my form?

*edit.py*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
      lang="en"
      metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
      i18n:domain="product.faq">
    <body>
        <metal:main fill-slot="content-core">
            <metal:content-core define-macro="content-core">
                <h2>This is a Edit Form</h2>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><strong>Plone's Title is: </strong><i tal:content="context/Title"></i></li>
                    <li><strong>Plone's Description is: </strong><i tal:content="context/Description"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-horizontal clearfix" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="faqQuestion" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Question</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input tal:attributes="value context/title" type="textfield" class="form-control" id="faqQuestion" placeholder="Enter a question">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="faqAnswer" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Answer</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input tal:attributes="value context/answer" type="textfield" class="form-control" id="faqAnswer" placeholder="Enter a answer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="faqSection" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Section</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input tal:attributes="value context/section" type="textfield" class="form-control" id="faqSection" placeholder="Enter a grouping">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
                       <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                   </div>
               </form>
           </metal:content-core>
       </metal:main>
   </body>
</html>
```

My other issue is that how do I create a custom add view? When I click add my url points to `http://localhost:8080/demo/faq/++add++product.faq.question`. Is the ++add++ denoting that it is a widget?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See docs for [`++add++`-traversal-adapter](https://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/advanced/custom-add-and-edit-forms.html#content-add-sequence), [customize add-form](https://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/advanced/custom-add-and-edit-forms.html#custom-add-forms), [customize edit-form](http://developer.plone.org/content/dexterity.html#custom-edit-form) and tell us, if you could proceed with them. Info: The docs are spreaded over different places but I read, there are plans to consolidate them soon :)

Comment: @IdaEbkes I have looked over the provided docs but I have not been able to figure it out yet. I have tried the dexterity.AddForm and the gork.form methods. Like I previously stated I can get my custom edit form to show but not a custom add form.

Comment: It looks like you were not following the docs. Ideally you do that, describe each step and at which point exactly what didn't work. Maybe you want to explain the usecase, too. Regards, Ida

Answer (score 4):

For your custom dexterity add/edit form, you might want to read the dexterity documentation at http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/custom-add-and-edit-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Please go through following url, I followed it for my custom add and edit view, and it worked http://developer.plone.org/content/dexterity.html#custom-add-form-view

Note: It has  `DefaultAddForm`, `DefaultAddView` base class for custom `AddForm`